# What partitions do I need to replace to uninstall Ubuntu and re-install OSX?

Tags: partitioning, uninstall, macosx, ppc

I have a Emac (imac) PowerPC G4 1Gz/1GB RAM, ATI Radeon 9400 - 80GB / DVD RW+-

I have installed Ubuntu and it is running just fine.

However, the lack of flash functionality on the PPC architecture is a problem as need it for web development etc.

So, I want to roll back to OSX.

But, Ubuntu has removed some HDD partitions that apparently OSX CD/DVD's require to re-install.

Can anyone let me know what partitions are required, their type (ext4, hfa, fat etc) and sizes?

Have trawled the web and just seem to be going in circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can erase the disk with `diskutil`. Answering your question, your disk should look like this:

```
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *64.0 GB    disk1
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         63.2 GB    disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3
```

Ofcourse, the sizes are according to your disk.
To erase and reinit the disk, use: `diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ name disk1`